# Web scraping - Wait until <div> content has loaded

Tags: html, dart, web-scraping

I've been playing around with Dart lately and wanted to test some web-scraping with it. I wanted to fetch product info from a particular site, for example this one here:

https://elko.is/simar-og-gps/oneplus-nord-5g-blue-marble-5011101199

Where the goal was to extract the Title, price and image url. This worked out fine for me, until I got some "Lazy loading" issues on the server end. Notice when you open up that page, the image doesn't show up right away, instead it has a placeholder image.

How do I make the code wait until this placeholder goes away and then fetch the info?

Here is my method I use to extract the data.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

Future<Map> WebScrape(String url) async {
  var client = Client();
  Response response = await client.get(url);

  // Use html parser and query selector
  var document = parse(response.body);
  List<Element> imageLink = document.querySelectorAll('div.modal-body > div.big-image > img');
  List<Element> productName = document.querySelectorAll('h1.product-name');
  List<Element> productPrice = document.querySelectorAll('span.product-price');
  Map productInfo = {'image': null, 'title': 'N/A', 'price': 0};

  if (imageLink.length > 0) {
    productInfo['image'] = imageLink[0].attributes['src'];
  }
  if (productName.length > 0) {
    productInfo['title'] = productName[0].text;
  }
  if (productName.length > 0) {
    List<String> price = productPrice[0].text.replaceFirst('.', '').split(' ');
    productInfo['price'] = double.parse(price[0]);
  }
  return productInfo;
}
```

And when I run it, I get this result

```
{image: https://elko.is/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/elko-image-placeholder.png, title:  OnePlus Nord 5G - Blue Marble , price: 84995.0}
```

Comment: You can't do so in "pure" dart you need some kind of headless browser, check this https://pub.dev/packages/puppeteer

Comment: @Mattia Are you sure? The plan was using this inside an app as a proof of concept, I'd rather not including a headless browser in the app packages if I can avoid it :)

Comment: The image has a `data-lazy-src` attribute which is url of the full image. Use that.

Comment: @Stephen - Perfect, thanks. Didn't know that attribute as it seems to disappear after the loading has finished. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AdamFjeldsted No problem. When dealing with web scraping you are generally not executing javascript so it is best to look at the unmodified HTML. If you want or need to have javascript executed that is when a headless browser like Mattia mentioned would be required. If you are looking with a web browser ctrl-u on most will give you the unmodified source where as devtools/inspection tools generally give you the DOM in it;s current state (modified by javascript) as you are viewing it.